# IO::Socket::SSL seems to be ignoring SSL_VERIFY_NONE

Tags: perl, ssl, io-socket-ssl

IO::Socket::SSL seems to be ignoring SSL_VERIFY_NONE; this is on OSX 10.14.1 with perl 5.18.2 and CentOS 6.10 with perl 5.10.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#
#  sslt
#
#  Test ssl connections to self-signed sites
#

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::SSL qw( SSL_VERIFY_NONE );
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'https://internal_site:18443/rest/v1';
my $method = 'GET';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('sslt/0.1');
$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);

# Create a request
my $req = HTTP::Request->new($method => $url);

print STDERR "Raw request ($method): $url\n";

# Send request to the user agent and get a response back
my $res = $ua->request($req);
print STDERR "Raw response: ", $res->message, " (", $res->code, ")\n";

exit 0;
```

results in:

```
$ sslt
Raw request (GET): https://internal_site:18443/rest/v1
Raw response: Can't connect to internal_site:18443 (certificate verify failed) (500)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not IO::Socket::SSL ignoring `SSL_verify_mode` but LWP overriding it. From [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/release/LWP-Protocol-https/source/lib/LWP/Protocol/https.pm#L18):

```
sub _extra_sock_opts
{
    my $self = shift;
    my %ssl_opts = %{$self->{ua}{ssl_opts} || {}};
    if (delete $ssl_opts{verify_hostname}) {
        $ssl_opts{SSL_verify_mode} ||= 1;                  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        $ssl_opts{SSL_verifycn_scheme} = 'www';
    }
```

Thus, you have to set `verify_hostname` to 0 to actually disable validation. See also the ticket [LWP::Protocol::https discards 0 value for SSL_VERIFY_mode](https://github.com/libwww-perl/LWP-Protocol-https/issues/47).